# Multiple tables in a DB SQLite

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, create-table

I was working with one table and all my program is ok, but now I have to add another table to my database, and by logic this is the code :

```
package net.ShamanOperativo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class UsuariosSQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //Sentencia SQL para crear la tabla de Incidentes
    String sqlCreate = "CREATE TABLE Incidentes  ( idInterno INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  , codReg TEXT, codGr TEXT, entidad TEXT, codInc TEXT, loc TEXT, dom TEXT, sint TEXT, movil TEXT, sexo TEXT, edad INTEGER, estado TEXT, latitud DOUBLE, longitud DOUBLE,colorLoc TEXT, colorGr TEXT )";
    String sqlCreate2 = "CREATE TABLE Moviles (idInterno INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, numMovil TEXT, colMovil TEXT, estado TEXT, localidad TEXT, cantServ INTEGER)";
    String sqlCreateIndex = "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idxIdInterno ON Incidentes(idInterno)";

    public UsuariosSQLiteHelper(Context contexto, String nombre,
                               CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(contexto, nombre, factory, version);


    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //Se ejecuta la sentencia SQL de creación de la tabla
        db.execSQL(sqlCreate);
        db.execSQL(sqlCreateIndex);
        db.execSQL(sqlCreate2);




    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int versionAnterior, int versionNueva) {

        //Se elimina la versión anterior de la tabla
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Incidentes");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Moviles");


        //Se crea la nueva versión de la tabla
        db.execSQL(sqlCreate);
        db.execSQL(sqlCreate2);

    }
}
```

My table Incidentes is ok, it is which I was using always.. but I can't use the table Moviles,  I use my table here:

```
 UsuariosSQLiteHelper usdbh =
                new UsuariosSQLiteHelper(this, "DBIncidentes", null, 1);

            SQLiteDatabase db = usdbh.getWritableDatabase();         //Abro base de datos para escritura

            if(db != null)
            {

                 //db.execSQL("DELETE from Moviles");
                 for (int i=0; i<= (vecTotal.length) -1; i++) {



                String reg = vecTotal[i].toString(); 
                String [] inc = TextUtils.split(reg, "\\^");




                String numMovil = inc[0];
                String colMovil = inc[1];
                String estado = inc[2];
                String localidad = inc[3];
                String strCantServ = inc[4];

                Integer cantServ = Integer.parseInt(strCantServ);



                try{                

                    //Insertamos los datos en la tabla Incidentes
 db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Moviles ( idInterno, numMovil, colMovil, estado, localidad, cantServ) " +
             "VALUES ("+(i+1)+", '" + numMovil +"', '" + colMovil +"' , '" + estado +"', '" + localidad +"', " +cantServ +" )");



}

catch (Exception e)

{
    e.getMessage();


}
```

Is there another thing I have to do to handle two tables or more? It isn't the same adapter and just refering which table of the database I want to consult or add info?

When the program want to add info into Moviles, logcat says it can't because Moviles doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't anything extra you need to do for handling more than 1 table.

I think your table is not created because neither `onCreate()` (because your database already exists) nor`onUpdate()` (you never increased the database version you pass to the `UsuariosSQLiteHelper`, right?) is called.